# How to replace all occurrences of X between Y's?

Tags: python, regex, perl, sed

I'm not sure if this problem solvable with regular expressions (in Perl5 syntax), but here is self-explanatory example:

```
smth Y1 test X foo X Y2 bar X Y1 X X Y2
s/?/Z/g
smth Y1 test Z foo Z Y2 bar X Y1 Z Z Y2
```

Consider that Y1 always have a matching Y2 and there is no overlapping.

Comment: what must happen in this scenario ? `YXYXY`

Comment: in my dataset it is impossible to have nested or unmatched Y's

Comment: If your Y's are XML tags, you will want to use an XML parser as XML fundamentally cannot be parsed with regexes.

Comment: @glenn, I got your point. But I think, that in some (rare) cases it is worth to use regexes for simple transformations, which you can write as a simple one-liner you would need to run only once.

Comment: naw, use xlst for that (just kidding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$str = 'smth Y1 test X foo X Y2 bar X Y1 X X Y2';
$str =~ s/X(?=((?!Y1).)*Y2)/Z/g;
print $str; #smth Y1 test Z foo Z Y2 bar X Y1 Z Z Y2
```

Comment: `[^(Y1)]` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @ysth, could you, please, explain it further?

Comment: @Andrew `[^(Y2)]` means not `(`, `Y`, `1`, nor `)`

Answer (score 3):

A little awkward, but:

```
my $string = 'smth Y1 test X foo X Y2 bar X Y1 X X Y2';
$string =~ s/(Y1.*?Y2)/ (my $tmp = "$1") =~ tr!X!Z!; $tmp /ge;
print $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

My interpretive solution (in Perl):

```
$sample = 'smth Y1 test X foo X Y2 bar X Y1 X X Y2';
$sample =~ s/(?<=Y1) ((?:(?!Y1|Y2).)+) (?=Y2)/subX($1)/xeg;

sub subX {
  ($str) = @_;
  $str =~ s/X/Z/g;
  return $str;
}

print $sample;
```

Output:

smth Y1 test Z foo Z Y2 bar X Y1 Z Z Y2